# WPF: XAML property declarations not being set via Setters?

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, setter

I have a WPF application where I'm using dependency properties in codebehind which I want to set via XAML declarations.

e.g.

```
<l:SelectControl StateType="A" Text="Hello"/>
```

So in this example I have a `UserControl` called `SelectControl`, which has a property called `StateType` which manipulate some other properties in it's setter.

To help illustrate the problem, I've put another property called `Text` in the example, read on and I'll explain further.

Codebehind excerpt...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(String), typeof(SelectControl));

public String Text
{
  get { return (String)GetValue(TextProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StateTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StateType", typeof(String), typeof(SelectControl));

public String StateType
{
  get { return (String)GetValue(StateTypeProperty) }
  set
    {
      switch (value)
      {
        case "A":
          AnotherPropertyBoolean = true;
          break;
        case "B":
          AnotherPropertyBoolean = false;
          break;
       default:
         // this is only an example... 
      }
   }
}
```

Now, if I set a breakpoint on the setter (for either `StateType` or `Text`), it turns out it's never executed.

However values declared for `Text`, i.e. "Hello" appears in it's data bound `TextBox`, and of course it I bind another text control to `StateType`'s value I can see that too.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "CLR-wrappers" for dependency properties only get called when done through code.  XAML depends on the name specified in the DependencyProperty.Register(...) call.  So, instead of "extending" the logic of the setter for your dependency property like you did above, just put your custom logic in a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) function.