# WPF Controls and DependencyProperty on Custom Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a C# custom WPF control.  I have properties on the control that are based on DependencyProperty's.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStateProperty = 
 DependencyProperty.Register( "CurrentState", typeof(ControlStateEnum),
 typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(ControlStateEnum.Started));

public ControlStateEnum CurrentState
{
    get { return (ControlStateEnum) GetValue(CurrentStateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentStateProperty, value); }
}
```

Now, if I use the control, and try to use it, ala:

```
<myControls:MyCustomControl CurrentState="Loaded" />
```

The CurrentState never gets set to "Loaded" and remains "Started".  I want to make it capable of binding, but also capable of being set without binding...  Is there something I don't understand or am missing?

When I set a breakpoint on the setter, it doesn't update on the window load.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setters not run on Dependency Properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225373/setters-not-run-on-dependency-properties)

Comment: So, in the end the value was being set on the control from the XAML after the control had been initialized and loaded.  So the way to handle it was to add a PropertyChangedHandler on the DependencyProperty.  Thanks for the help in diagnosing it, parapura.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in the end the value was being set on the control from the XAML after the control had been initialized and loaded. So the way to handle it was to add a PropertyChangedHandler on the DependencyProperty.

parapura had a link to the right answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225373/setters-not-run-on-dependency-properties).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your not changed the enum somewhere else after the controls get loaded, because that should work as intended

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not appear that the setter is firing at all.

Comment: Its not going to...Not on initialization

Comment: The value does get changed and updated.  Unfortunately, this happens AFTER the control is loaded and constructed.  And as the other link suggests, the Setters/Getters are called via Get/SetValue, and we don't see it change.  Therefore, the only way to handle changes and catch them in the XAML is by having a callback.

Comment: After every sentence I said yes. I dont see the problem here

Comment: When you write `new PropertyMetadata(ControlStateEnum.Started))` that means the default value is started no matter when you do when constructing the control. Then this `CurrentState="Loaded"` overrides it. This is how ALL WPF controls work