# How can updating a Canvas attached property also update a bound view model property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm changing the position of a UIElement within a WPF Canvas by using the static `Canvas.SetTop` method in the code-behind (in the full application I'm using a complex Rx chain but for this example I've simplified it to a button click).

The problem I have is that the value of the attached property, Canvas.Top in the XAML, is bound to a property in my ViewModel. Calling `Canvas.SetTop` bypasses the `set` in my ViewModel so I don't get the updated value. How can I update the Canvas.Top value in the code-behind so that the ViewModel properties' setter is called?

XAML View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <Button Content="Move Button" Canvas.Top="{Binding ButtonTop}" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindowView : Window
    {
        public MainWindowView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop((UIElement) sender, Canvas.GetTop((UIElement) sender) + 5);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTopProperty = DependencyProperty.
            Register("ButtonTop", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));

        public int ButtonTop
        {
            get { return (int) GetValue(ButtonTopProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTopProperty, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ButtonTop = 15;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the `ButtonTop` binding two-way, like `Canvas.Top="{Binding ButtonTop, Mode=TwoWay}"`?

Comment: Adding `Mode=TwoWay` doesn't fix the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to *set [Binding Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to TwoWay*:

```
<Button Content="Move Button" Canvas.Top="{Binding ButtonTop, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
```

Also, if you are setting it from code behind, set using [SetCurrentValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue.aspx) method otherwise *binding will be broken and ViewModel instance won't be updated*:

```
UIElement uiElement = (UIElement)sender;
uiElement.SetCurrentValue(Canvas.TopProperty, Canvas.GetTop(uiElement) + 5);
```

---

Like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4225429/632337), do not write code in wrapper properties of DP's:

> The WPF binding engine calls `GetValue` and `SetValue` directly (bypassing
>   the property setters and getters).

If you need to synchronize on property change, create a *PropertyChangedCallback* and do synchronization over there:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTopProperty = DependencyProperty.
        Register("ButtonTop", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindowViewModel),
                    new UIPropertyMetadata(ButtonTopPropertyChanged));

    private static void ButtonTopPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender,
                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Write synchronization logic here
    }
```

Otherwise *simply have normal CLR property* and you should consider implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on your class:

```
private double buttonTop;
public double ButtonTop
{
   get { return buttonTop; }
   set
   {
      if(buttonTop != value)
      {
         // Synchronize here
         buttonTop = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I set a breakpoint after your code change and (exactly the same as my initial code) the ViewModel property value is updated, but the `set` method was not called. I need the setter to be called in the ViewModel because it performs additional synchronisation between the ViewModel and the Model. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: It will work for normal CLR property and not for DP. When value is set via XAML wrapper properties never gets called. Read more about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225373/setters-not-run-on-dependency-properties).