# Bind Control/Window property to custom property and set default value

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the `Title` property of a `Window` to a custom property of this `Window`. The XAML looks like this:

```
Title="{Binding Path=WindowTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
```

The code behind like this:

```
public string WindowTitle
{
    get
    {
        string title = (string)GetValue(WindowTitleProperty);
        title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) ? "Editor" : title;
        return title;
    }

    set
    {
        SetValue(WindowTitleProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowTitleProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("WindowTitle", typeof(string), typeof(Editor), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

This works good after the property `WindowTitle` was set to a new value. But unfortunately upon loading the `Window` I don't get any title. The getter of `WindowTitle` isn't even called. As far as I can say, it never gets called. What am I doing wrong? Why is the getter never called (even when the title is set correctly)? Can I set a defaultvalue on any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: XAML property declarations not being set via Setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836076/wpf-xaml-property-declarations-not-being-set-via-setters)

Comment: Although the referenced question is about setters (not getters), the reason is the same. Please read the answer there.

Comment: The detailed explanation is here: [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property looks strange. Why is it defined as a dependency property to begin with? You might as well use a CLR property and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This works fine for me:

```
public partial class Window13 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window13()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _windowTitle = "default title...";
    public string WindowTitle
    {
        get { return _windowTitle; }
        set { _windowTitle = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

The CLR getter of a dependency property should only call the `GetValue` method and not contain any other logic.

**Edit:**
If you do want a dependency property for some reason, it should be implemented like this:

```
public string WindowTitle
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(WindowTitleProperty);
    }

    set
    {
        SetValue(WindowTitleProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowTitleProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("WindowTitle", typeof(string), typeof(Editor), new UIPropertyMetadata("Editor"));
```

Note that you specify the default value when you register the property.

Comment: Setting the default value was the missing part for me thanks. Just to lear something: Is it good practice to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a Window?

Comment: Not really. You typically set the DataContext of a window to a view model class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and then bind to properties of the view model. But any class, including a window, can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged if it makes sense.

Comment: For this Window I use the same ViewModel as for my MainWindow. I need access to some components of that ViewModel but don't want to put stuff from other Windows than the MainWindow in it. I think I should implement a seperate ViewModel for the childform which has Acces to the MainWindow ViewModel then. Thanks for your help!